# python list comprehension transform

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to understand when should one use list comprehension. a lot of time, it is convenient and save lines. But sometimes, it does not work as expected?

if I have:

```
listA = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

I can use a for loop

```
for i in listA:
    print(i)
```

obviously this will give me:

```
1
2
3
4
```

what if I try:

```
print(i for i in listA)
```

but this won't give me the same result?

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x102a3b3b8>
```

How should I understand this?

My additional question is:
if I have a for loop followed by one line of codes, can one always write it in a way using comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a list comprehension. You passed in a *generator expression* to `print()`. The `print()` function does not iterate over any arguments you pass in; it only sends the `str()` conversion to `stdout`.

If you wanted to send all values in the generator to `print()`, use `*(...)`:

```
print(*(i for i in listA))
```

Here that's overkill, you could just do the same for the values in `listA`:

```
print(*listA)
```

Both will print the values with the default separator, a space. If you wanted to have newlines, tell `print()` to use `\n` as the separator:

```
print(*(i for i in listA), sep='\n')
print(*listA, sep='\n')
```

And no, not every `for` loop is suitable to be converted to a list comprehension. A list comprehension *creates a new list object*, and not all loops build lists.

If you have a list of the form:

```
some_name = []
for <target> in <iterable>:
    some_name.append(<expression>)
```

then you can convert that to a list comprehension:

```
some_name = [<expression> for <target> in <iterable>]
```

Answer (score 1):

A **generator** is an object that can be iterated over. It is not intended to be printed.

List comprehensions come in two forms, with and without brackets:

```
print(i for i in listA)
print([i for i in listA])
```

The first one produces an iterator object while the other produces an actual list.

For your problem you could do:

```
print(*listA, sep='\n')
```

In general, list comprehensions should be avoided when they make code obscure. Why not use a simple for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
listA = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
# option 1
print(*listA, sep='\n')
# option 2
for p in listA: print (p)
```